# useEffect is not always executed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

There is a component:

```js
function Blogs(props) {
    const [links, setLinks] = useState([]);

    function getBlogs() {
        const ids = props.ids;
        for (const id of ids) {
            getBlog(id).then(blog => setLinks([...links, <Link to={`/blog/${id}`}>{blog.name}</Link>]));
        }
    }

    async function getBlog(id) {
        let data = await fetch(`${root}/api/blog/${id}`);
        data = await data.json();
        const blog = data.blog;
        return blog;
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        getBlogs();
    }, []);

    return (
        <div className="profile-blogs">
            <div className="a">Блоги</div>
            <div className="b">
                {links}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

links is an array with jsx links. Link exported from react-router-dom. The problem is that useEffect is not always executed, that is, often when a component is called, useEffect simply does not work. I have a guess that this is because of react-router-dom's navigation, as its links do not refresh the page, but I have no idea how to fix this.

Comment: Since you have provided an empty dependency array it will only run on the first render. see: [useEffect: Conditionally firing an effect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#conditionally-firing-an-effect)

Comment: With the empty array it will be called just once

Comment: @pilchard, I understand, but I don’t know what to convey depending on

Comment: It looks like you rely on `props.ids` to fetch blog posts, so perhaps add that as the dependency: `useEffect(() => { getBlogs();}, [props.ids]);`. When the ids sent to the component change, refetch blogs.

Comment: @pilchard, Yeah, It's working!